# Recent items are showing under "No Date" when sorting by date in finder

Tags: finder, sort

This thing's driving me crazy.

Often, when I download or create a new file, and then I have to upload it to a website or something like that, it will appear after the oldest items under a "No Date" section.

I'm running Mountain Lion but it happened for me at Lion as well.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This happens when the files in question have a "Date Modified" in the future.

Comment: OK. Why would this happen? Is this a timezone issue?

Comment: The file metadata may be corrupt.

Comment: I have only experienced this in Chrome's Open dialog - are you experiencing this as a general issue in Finder or just in Chrome?

Comment: There is a similar thread in the Apple Support discussion forum - but no fix: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3272875?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @EmilRasmussen currently I can reproduce this only on chrome but I'm pretty sure in the past it happened in general finder windows or other apps' open dialogs as well.

Comment: Well I had the issue only on the Downloads folder every other folder would show the date,  I had no files in the future. The workaround for me was when I was in the Downloads folder the show Last modified was unchecked checked it and all is normal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know if this is really a "solution" per se, but it's a workaround that I prefer anyway: I changed the "Arrange by" to "None" as described here [Mac OS X - File Open Dialog: Can't sort or resize columns](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99365/mac-os-x-file-open-dialog-cant-sort-or-resize-columns)

This gets rid of the categorization by Today/7 days/30 days/etc. altogether, and just gives a straightforward dialog that lets you sort however you want (be it Date Modified, or Name, or Size). I find this much more useful and fail to see the advantage of the other view (which is made almost useless by this No Date bug).

Note that some applications (e.g., MS Office) do not let you change the Auto-arrange setting. Just open up some other application that does (e.g., Chrome) and set it there (just go to Open File or similar -- you don't have to actually open the file). This action seems to set this setting globally (on 10.8.4).

This problem is all over the web. Why does Apple not comment on it? Does it not care about its users? Why does it not release a fix? Is iTunes so much more important? This bug seems almost ludicrous: The arrange-by setting used for categorization is (normally) "Date Modified", and the actual modified date is clearly shown in the Date Modified column. Indexing in the general case perhaps needs to happen *not* in real time (e.g., if you are viewing "All Files"), but when we open a dialog, can't just the (usually very few but most important) No Date files be manually indexed in that moment?

Comment: It is now 2015, almost 2016.  Has Apple made any fix to this?  Or is this workaround the only viable option?
Completely agree with givo -> why won't Apple fix these ludicrous counterintuitive configurations!?!?!

Comment: Note that sorting by Date Created seems to have fixed this for me also.

Comment: Im still having the issue.
macOS Sierra
10.12.6

Comment: This worked for me. OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Im seeing it in Mojave, 10.14.04

Comment: It's not a solution. Six years and three months later (!!) this bug -- and that's what it is, a bug -- still exists.

Comment: Hello from 2020 - it's still a problem.

Comment: 2021 jumping on the bandwagon

Comment: 2022; still broken

Answer (score 8):

Understanding the reason for this bug may help people handle it. The bug occurs when applications have been opened on a previous day and stay open overnight. If you use the application on the next day, it'll show files with "no date" because - in the context of that application - the file has been created in the future.

A workaround is to close the application in which you use that "Open" or "Save" dialogue and open it again. This bug is very annoying and I can't understand why Apple doesn't fix it.

Comment: Whoa. You just blew my mind. And now I realize this is happening to me because I haven't close Chrome in seven months.

Answer (score 3):

First, Force quit Finder. You can do this by pressing the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> keys and then selecting Finder from the list and clicking on the <kbd>Relaunch</kbd> button.

Then, try deleting the Finder's preferences file: com.apple.finder.plist, found in ~/Library/Preferences.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

This file seems to easily become corrupt. Trashing it is a good first step when Views become wacky—anything to do with Finder.

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: I relaunched after deleting the file and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just click on Today, and it should update the downloads to their correct date.

Comment: Didn't work. OS X El Capitan 10.11.6