# Mac OS X - File Open Dialog: Can't sort or resize columns

Tags: mac

I'm having a problem where when I go to File > Open; I can't resize the different columns.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Set the arrange by mode to none:

[image]
[image]

Comment: WOW That worked. It's been bothering me for weeks, thank you!

Comment: Thanks.  Note that sorting by Date Created seems to have fixed this for me also.